# How to make production ready connection between VNET and Web app for containers?

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I am struggling with picking right solution for given scenario:

This is how VNet is looking now:

[image]

1. Gateway is showing adress from 10.10.XXX.XXX.
2. Connection is policy based and it **CAN'T** be changed
3. Currently public IPs are used for development and tunneling purposes

**Problem:**

We have *[WebApp for Containers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/containers/)* with Docker image A. Container needs to see **10.10.100.1:1234** IP. As TEMP solution we are opening ssh tunnel connection from inside 
Web SSH:

> ssh -L 5555:10.10.100.1:1234 user@123.123.123.123

(public IP)

[image]

This is working but we need to make it in a proper way. We are not able to use [VNet Integration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) because it is in preview and it is not working. We **CAN'T** make more changes in Gateway configuration.

So the question is:

**How to make it work without tunneling using as much azure as possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only really have 3 supported solutions for vNet integration in Web Apps:

- vNet Integration for web apps currently in preview
- virtual network gateway connection
- [App service environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro) providing a single tenanted web app in your vNet

Sounds like the first two won't work for you given your requirements, so using ASE is the only option left, but be aware this is an expensive option.

Comment: We have used ASE. It is working in given case.